# How to do a customise discrete slider like below one in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have tried to achieve using slider and slider theme flutter lib.

- even i went through property and functions of slider but i am not able get idea how to achieve this one, can anyone help or any idea please to share or guide me.
  [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flutter has `Slider` Widget which has almost all the properties that can be customized except for the divider property, for that we can add `Container` on top of `Slider` to give that separation appearance.

Complete Code : -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const Box(),
    );
  }
}

class Box extends StatefulWidget {
  const Box({super.key});

  @override
  State<Box> createState() => _BoxState();
}

void g() {}

class _BoxState extends State<Box> {
  double sliderValue = 50;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliderTheme(
      data: SliderThemeData(
          trackHeight: 80,
          thumbShape: SliderComponentShape.noOverlay,
          overlayShape: SliderComponentShape.noOverlay,
          valueIndicatorShape: SliderComponentShape.noOverlay,
          activeTrackColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 9, 84, 146),
          trackShape: const RectangularSliderTrackShape()),
      child: Scaffold(
          body: Center(
              child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 250,
            width: 80,
            child: RotatedBox(
              quarterTurns: 3,
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25)),
                child: Slider(
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      sliderValue = value;
                    });
                  },
                  value: sliderValue,
                  min: 0,
                  max: 100,
                  divisions: 4,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 250,
            width: 80,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 1,
                  width: 80,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 1,
                  width: 80,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 1,
                  width: 80,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ))),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]